# iOS: assigning a class to a xib, and not recognizing it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm using the following code to load a xib in my UIView subclass named ImageWithCaptionView.
I've specified in the xib Inspector the name of the view: ImageWithCaptionView.

However the if statement (isKindOfClass) is never true, and I've to remove it to make things work. What am I missing here ?

```
    UINib *nib = [[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ImageWithCaptionView class]) bundle:nil] retain];

    NSArray *myArray = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];  

     for (id currentObject in myArray) {
         if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ImageWithCaptionView class]]) {
             self = (ImageWithCaptionView *) currentObject;
             break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Where did you specify it in the inspector?

Comment: @Nick Weaver In the Identify and Type tab: http://d.pr/bZcx

Comment: Can you switch to the identity inspector tab? Three tabs from the left. There's a field "Custom Class", is your class listed there?

Comment: @Nick Weaver Damn, the tab was empty without selecting an object in the UIBuilder.. thanks solved, if you post an answer I can vote it.

Comment: Glad to hear that and done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the class is also set in the Custom Class field in the identity inspector tab.